# What project type GUID should I use for a utility project?

Tags: visual-studio

This question is related to [How to code a utility msbuild project so that it depends on a "real" C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194062/how-to-code-a-utility-msbuild-project-so-that-it-depends-on-a-real-c-sharp-pro)

In my current solution the project type GUID used for the utility project is that of C# (SDK style). This does not seem right. Is there a more suitable project type GUID?

I looked in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802387/ and https://www.codeproject.com/reference/720512/list-of-visual-studio-project-type-guids , but nothing seems to be quite right.

Comment: Please note that newbedev is a Stack Exchange scraper; don't link to it. Instead, google the text or title, and find the correct link to the network, instead of giving scrapers more traffic that they don't deserve.

Comment: @Zoe - makes sense and my bad. Will be more attentive the next time.